# Need help figuring which class to modify for making changes in how spark dataframe/sql inner join is implemented

Tags: apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

I want to make some changes to how inner join resturns output. basically i want to iterate left dataset after the first hit, and i don't want to do a distinct on my right dataframe to save cost.

I'm hoping this would be a simple impleemntation where instead of iterating with comparison (leftKey < rightKey), i'll do leftItr.next() when there's a match.

But i'm struggling to figure out the implementation where i need to make these chagnes.
i tried adding debugger in SortMergeJoinExec class, however the checkpoint hits only during planning phase, I've hard coded hints to always use sortMergeJoin so that spark doesn't do the smart thing for my testing.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.
i basically want to package a new jar and ship it so that other projects can just include that jar, and use "customInnerJoin" as a joinType in sql/dataframe operations